# Removing an object from NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

How can I remove an object in my NSMutableArray? I tried to use `[myArray removeObject:@"Music"]` but it didn't work. I cannot use `[myArray removeObjectAtIndex:4]` cause the position of the array is dynamic. The problem here is inside the array I have 7 objects, each object is a NSDictionary. And I need to remove the object which has the **Music** title or tag. How can I do it? Thanks!

Comment: please share your code you have done

Comment: Please provide at least a sample value of your `NSMutableArray`.

Answer (score 2):

Your Removed string is @"Music".  it is contain in the array.
So you will get the index of the require string.

```
BOOL Success = [yourArray containsObject:@"Music"];  // that bool response is whether the string present or not
if(Success){
    NSInteger index = [yourArray indexOfObject:@"Music"];   // it return the matched string index value form array
   [yourArray removeObjectAtIndex:index]
}
```

Comment: That's what `removeObject:` does anyway.

Comment: @Droppy, no if you read the documentation, `removeObject:` will remove every occruence of an object from the array, whereas `removeObjectAtIndex:` will only remove the occurence at the specified index. If using `removeObject:` on an array with no duplicate occurrences, the result will be indistinguishable but the behavior is different

Answer (score 0):

First find the elements that should be removed.

```
// this is one of many ways to find some things in array, in this case returning an index of the match
NSIndexSet *indexSet = [myArray indexesOfObjectPassingTest:^(id o, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){ 
    NSDictionary *d = (NSDictionary *)o;
    BOOL isMusic = [d[@"title"] isEqualToString:@"Music"];  // put the real test here
    return isMusic;
}];
```

Now `removeObjectAtIndex:` will work as expected.

```
[indexSet enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    [myArray removeObjectAtIndex:idx];
}];
```

EDIT - Even more concise, replace the enumeration above with:

```
[myArray removeObjectsAtIndexes:indexSet];
```

Comment: But, how can I do it if I have 2 remove 2 or more element?

Comment: sure.  just use the plural form of the search, then enumerate the result to remove.  (see edits)

Comment: Why is your code any different to `[NSMutableArray removeObject:]`?

Comment: @Droppy removeObject takes as its parameter the object to be removed. The point of the answer is how to get that object when what you start with is only a criterion that describes it.

Comment: @danh Indeed; I really ought to start reading the whole question :)